# High amount of links from a low Trust Flow website

Tags: seo, backlinks

My website is having more than 20000 backlinks from a news portal site. As measured by Majestic SEO, the Trust Flow of the news portal website is 0 and Citation Flow is 19. At the same time, my website has a Trust Flow of 7 and Citation Flow of 37.

Will having such a high amount of backlinks from a relatively low Trust Flow site harm the reputation of my site?

Comment: In my experience a large number of links from a single website have little to no effect on rankings, either positively or negatively.   I was worried when a porn site linked to my site from every page, but nothing bad ever came of it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a high CF:TF ratio *can* be a signal of a website having a lot of low-quality links. An ideal CF:TF ratio is 1 and no more than 1.8 [1](https://moz.com/community/q/trust-flow-is-greater-than-citation-flow-how-do-we-analyse-those-domains)

It's worth remembering that TF and CF are just indications and are not necessarily taken into account by Google (Google analyses much, much more than just the volume and quality of links).

If you're worried that this is having a negative effect on your rankings, I would suggest you either contact the webmaster/editor of the news website, or disavow the domain in GWT.

**Remember** - if you disavow the domain, your CF will not change, despite Google discounting the domain. CF / TF are Majestic metrics, not directly linked to Google.

[Trust flow is greater than citation flow, how do we analyse those domains](https://moz.com/community/q/trust-flow-is-greater-than-citation-flow-how-do-we-analyse-those-domains)

Comment: In your opinion what whould be desired action from the webmaster of the news website? Will he delete the backlinks?

Comment: If you feel that the news portal is spammy, or there is no value in your sites linking, then I would suggest that the webmaster delete the backlinks.